# The reason for why componentWillMount is not ok for side effects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sure, componentWillMount is not something talk about now due to it being obsolete but I came across the react docs and it says that

> componentWillMount is called before render which means setting state
> synchronously in componentWillMount will not cause extra render call.

Is it true that setState will not work in that lifecycle method at all?

Comment: Well, for one, [because it's deprecated](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#componentwillmount) and will be removed in future versions of React. Don't use it. If you need a true effect (which means that what happens _does not affect the component itself_) then its timing does not depend on whether the component is "just about to be mounted", it depends on whether the component exists or not, which is whether it's mounted or not. But since you're asking about an old function, and the old `setState`: which version of React are you using? Because it sounds like "not the current one".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, no no I have created this question purely to understand why componentWillMount is not ok for side effects then I came across react docs but I doubted a bit thus created this question. So, is it true that setState does not work in that hook?

Comment: _What hook_? Because `setState` is not a hook, `useState` is a hook, `useEffect` is a hook, etc. but `setState` is an instance function that you get when you write a class that extends `React.Component` and has nothing to do with hooks.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you consider "not working".

In class components, `setState` serves two purposes:

1. Update `this.state` of the component
2. Indicate to React that the components needs to re-render

`componentWillMount` according to the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#unsafe_componentwillmount) (for the non-deprecated name `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`) "will [be called] immediately after the constructor." which also means it is called before your component is ever rendered initially.
You *can* technically use `setState` within the function to update `this.state` but it will not call the `render` method in addition to manipulating `this.state`. `render` will be called later for the initial render.

Couple other notes from the docs:

> `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` is the only lifecycle method that runs during server rendering. For all practical purposes, it is identical to `constructor`, so you should use the `constructor` for this type of logic instead.

> Calling `setState` inside `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` in a class component to initialize state is equivalent to passing that state as the initial state to `useState` in a function component.

*... which is pretty much equivalent to defining the initial state as field in the class component or setting `this.state` in the constructor*.

Especially that last quote seems to indicate that it *will* update `this.state`.

So back to your question: "Is it true that setState will not work in that lifecycle method at all?" If "working" means "setting the state of the component", it *will* do that. If "working" means "causes the `render` function to be called again", the answer is no (because it doesn't make sense to do that before the initial render.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer). I kindly want to ask a question on why componentWillMount should not contain side effects like api calls. Nicholas Tower explained above that it is because we will face double render, that is, during the first render api call is executed then React will NOT wait that api call finish and continue rendering. Then, api call gets the result and setState is executed and there happens ADDITIONAL re-render. But with componentDidMount we will have just ONE render. Is that true?

Comment: Honestly, not sure! My assumption is that `setState` will first check internal properties on the component instance to see whether it has been mounted and if so, will indeed rerender, regardless of the lifecycle method it's been called from. So if the api call takes longer than the initial render, it might actually cause another render. Easiest way to know is to try it out :) Or if you want to be sure that things behave the way you want them to, move to `componentDidMount` instead where you are guaranteed that the component has mounted.

Comment: `But with componentDidMount we will have just ONE render. ` Btw, i did not say that part. If you're doing async side effects, you will always have 2 renders. My point was that with `componentDidMount` the developer **expects** it to have 2 renders, while `componentWillMount` gives you a false sense that it will just render once, but then it renders twice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that setState will not work in that lifecycle method at all?

That's incorrect. That comment is pointing out that if you synchronously set state during `componentWillMount`, then the very first render of the component will be able to include those state changes. As such, react doesn't need to do an *extra* render, because the normal first render is sufficient.

So the page will render with the state you set. It just does that in one render, not two.

Comment: then please can you very briefly explain why componentWillMount should not contain side effects? I have been looking for the information for several days 

Comment: People would sometimes get in the mind set that if they write their code in componentWillMount, they can skip a render (for performance). But this is only true if you're doing synchronous code. If you have asynchronous side effects such as fetching data, you're always going to need two renders. So componentWillMount gives the developer a false sense of security. componentDidMount makes it clear that the fetch happen after the initial render, and so is the better place for asynchronous side effects.